# Generating Maven artifacts for Eclipse EMF jars

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, emf

I've got a project that was generator using EMF and depends on some EMF 2.5.0 jars. Specifically the Maven dependencies:

```
org.eclipse.emf.ecore:xmi:jar:2.5.0
org.eclipse.emf:common:jar:2.5.0
org.eclipse.emf:ecore:jar:2.5.0
```

I've tried running the following Maven command to populate my local repository:

```
mvn eclipse:make-artifacts -DstripQualifier=true -DeclipseDir=./
```

And this successfully pulls in the jars but at the wrong version (2.8.0). I've tried using these instead but it turns out I'm missing another dependency:

```
org.eclipse.equinox:org.eclipse.equinox.app:jar:1.0.0
```

Does anybody know if there's a way of generating a complete set of EMF Maven artifacts?

Thanks,

Jon

Comment: Is your project an eclipse plugin? Maybe you should check out Tycho first.

Comment: No it's not an eclipse plugin. I used EMF to generate Java code from an XML schema which I'm using as a client library for a specific type of web service. EMF probably wasn't the best way to do this, but it was quick.